# Extract all data from table by name in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, database, ms-access, sqlalchemy

I connect to a database in MS Access using SQL Alchemy:

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:/Users/mvideo/Desktop/dataBase.accdb;'
    r'ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;'
)
connection_uri = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
engine = create_engine(connection_uri)
print (engine.table_names())
```

THe result is

```
['Air', 'regions', 'Soil', 'water']
```

I get names of all tables. I want to get query from on of this table (with name of `water`). How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import text

t = text("SELECT * FROM water")

connection = engine.connect()

result = connection.execute(t)
```

Comment: It does not work at all...Maybe result = engine.execute(t)? And how I should get infromation?

Comment: check if you missed this : connection = engine.connect()

Comment: You might have better luck with `result = connection.execute(t).fetchall()`